# Quadratic minimization contains inverse

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

This is a simple question but I do not understand how to do it and I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. Consider the optimization problem

\begin{align}
\text{minimize } &\quad x^T P x \\
\text{subject to} & \quad Ax-b \leq 0.
\end{align}
Why does the dual problem contain $P^{-1}$ ?

The dual function is $g(\lambda) = -\frac14 \lambda^T A P^{-1} A^T \lambda - b^T \lambda$.

---

Here's my work: The Lagrangian is
$$ L(x,\lambda) = x^TPx + \lambda^T(Ax -b)).
$$
The dual function is 
$$
g(\lambda) = \inf_x L(x,\lambda) .
$$

Comment: Did you try writing down the Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda)$ and minimizing it with respect to $x$  in order to find the dual function? What step did you get stuck on?

Comment: I updated my question and i got stuck at this @littleO

Comment: You can minimize with respect to $x$ by setting the gradient with respect to $x$ equal to $0$, then solving for $x$.

Comment: Solving for first derivative?

Comment: @littleO how do I get the negative sign? I got (-1/2)(-1/2) which would give me 1/4. Where did the negative sign come from

Comment: I attempted to edit the question for clarity; but if you don't agree with the edit I can roll it back. I noticed that this Wikipedia page gives a derivation of the dual problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Lagrangian_duality

Comment: @littleO I think this is fine. But I cannot seem to get he negative sign jn front although I managed to get the expression

Comment: Oh I got it now thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that $P$ is symmetric positive definite. The Lagrangian is

$$
L(x, \lambda) = x^T P x + \lambda^T (Ax - b).
$$

We can minimize $L$ with respect to $x$ by setting the gradient of $L$ with respect to $x$ equal to $0$:
$$
2Px + A^T \lambda = 0 \implies
x = -\frac12 P^{-1} A^T \lambda.
$$

Plugging in for $x$, we find that the dual function is

\begin{align}
g(\lambda) &= (-\frac12 P^{-1} A^T \lambda)^T P (-\frac12 P^{-1} A^T \lambda) + \lambda^T A (-\frac12 P^{-1} A^T \lambda) - \lambda^T b \\
&= \frac14 \lambda^T A P^{-1} P P^{-1} A^T \lambda - \frac12 \lambda^T A P^{-1} A^T \lambda - \lambda^T b \\
&= -\frac14 \lambda^T A P^{-1} A^T \lambda - \lambda^T b.
\end{align}

Comment: Is this the consistent method for all kinds of quadratic minimization?

Comment: sry forgot to tag u

Comment: @aceminer I think this is a typical example, but if $P$ is only positive semidefinite then the calculation requires a bit more care.

Comment: For singular $P$, what I have often seen is that the dual is written with the primal variable still there; e.g.,$$\begin{array}{ll}\text{maximize} & -x^TPx - b^T\lambda \\ \text{subject to} & 2Px + A^T\lambda = 0\\&\lambda\geq 0\end{array}$$Of course, generally you're supposed to eliminate the primal variable; that's the whole point of the Langrangian method. But in this case you get lucky because this form of the dual is actually jointly convex in $x$ and $\lambda$.